# Spawn Argument Array Element with Quotes

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am using [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to execute `latexmk` with `child_process.spawn command, args, options` where `command = 'latexmk'` and the `args` array is

```
["-interaction=nonstopmode", "-f", "-cd", "-pdf", "-synctex=1", "-file-line-error", "-shell-escape", "-xelatex", "-outdir="/Users/user/Documents/path with space/.auxdir"", ""/Users/user/Documents/path with space/main.tex""]
```

The `options` just set some environment variables. I get the following from `stderr`:

```
stderr: mkdir ": Permission denied at /usr/texbin/latexmk line 1889.
```

`latexmk` seems to be trying to search for a path that contains the `"`. The quotes are necessary in case of whitespace in the path. What can I do to solve this?

EDIT:

To be clear, I need to populate `outdir` and the `filePath` like so:

```
args.push("-outdir=\"#{outdir}\"")
args.push("\"#{filePath}\"")
```

Problem is that `"\'#{}\'"` gives me the literal strings.

Comment: @muistooshort: According to `latexmk --help` it requires `-output-directory=dir or -outdir=dir`. I need to test your first proposal because I need the same array to be compatible with executing `latexmk` with the `exec` child process as well. The issue I have with your second proposal is mentioned in my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

For a given `program`, I needed to have two cases in which I would use it. One when it would return a `buffer` and the other when it returned a `stream`. From the nodejs documentation, `exec` is used for the former while `spawn` is used for the latter. I wanted to share the same arguments except for maybe and extra `arg_i` thrown in there for `spawn`. The issue I faced was finding a solution that handled whitespace. The following resolves the issue:

```
args= ["arg1", "arg2", "...", "arg_i", "...", "arg_n", "path /with /space"]
```

For `exec`:

```
escapedArgs = (item.replace(' ', '\\ ') for item in args)
command = "program #{escapedArgs.join(' ')}"
proc = child_process.exec command, options, (error, stdout, stderr)
```

For `spawn`, `args` does not need to be modified:

```
proc = child_process.spawn command, args, options
```